# How to avoid using a lot of issets?

Tags: php

I'm working in a PHP project where I have 7 types of users, so I have to anticipate 7 $_SESSION variables for every type of user. Is there a way I can avoid doing this in every PHP file?

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: .');
}

if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
    header('Location: views/admin/');
}

if (isset($_SESSION['info'])) {
    header('Location: views/informatica/');
}

if (isset($_SESSION['subA'])) {
    header('Location: views/subA/');
}

if (isset($_SESSION['subB'])) {
    header('Location: views/subB/');
}

if (isset($_SESSION['oficina'])) {
    header('Location: views/oficina/');
}

if (isset($_SESSION['compras'])) {
    header('Location: views/compras/');
}

if (isset($_SESSION['auditoria'])) {
    header('Location: views/auditoria/');
}
```

Comment: Will more than one of those be set?  If so you have them checked in a certain order?

Comment: There is nothing inherently "wrong" with the above code, it works. The design is not pretty, but redesign it would be a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: /');
    exit();
}

$rolesLocations = [
    'admin' => '/views/admin',
    'info' => '/views/informatica',
    'subA' => '/views/subA',
    'subB' => '/views/subB',
    'oficina' => '/views/oficina',
    'compras' => '/views/compras',
    'auditoria' => '/views/auditoria',
];

foreach ($rolesLocations as $role => $location) {
    if (isset($_SESSION[$role])) {
        header('Location: ' . $location);
    }
}
```

Comment: Best to have an explicit `exit()` after doing the redirect, or at least a `break`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of separate variables, use one variable `$_SESSION['usertype']`.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['usertype'])) {
    header("Location: views/{$_SESSION['usertype']}/");
}
```